# Parsing number from excel using java

Tags: java, database, parsing, casting, poi-hssf

I have a code that will gather a number from excel file and store it into DB MySql.

> String P01_PickModul =  row.getCell(13).getStringCellValue();

The problem is i can not gather the number with more decimal, for example 1.04166666666667

I set the data type on sql as double.

Can you help me with this issue?
thank you.

Comment: What's the cell type? `row.getCell(###).getCellType()` - is it a numeric cell or a string cell?

Comment: sorry, it is string cell

Answer (score 0):

try using `long` as the data type and check weather it works.

Answer (score 0):

try row.getDouble(13) and your pick modul should be double, but I dont know, what type your "row" is so it maybe won't work